# JFreeChart - How to create BarRenderer ToolTip

Tags: jsf-2, jfreechart

Does BarRenderer Tooltip is working with jsf ?

```
 private JFreeChart createChart(CategoryDataset categorydataset) {
    JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart3D("Stacked Bar Chart 3D Demo 1", null, "Value", categorydataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
    CategoryPlot categoryplot = (CategoryPlot) jfreechart.getPlot();
    IntervalMarker intervalmarker = new IntervalMarker(5D, 10D, Color.gray, new BasicStroke(0.5F), Color.blue, new BasicStroke(0.5F), 0.5F);
    categoryplot.addRangeMarker(intervalmarker);
    BarRenderer barrenderer = (BarRenderer) categoryplot.getRenderer();
    barrenderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);
    barrenderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator());
    barrenderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
    barrenderer.setBasePositiveItemLabelPosition(new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.CENTER, TextAnchor.CENTER));
    barrenderer.setBaseNegativeItemLabelPosition(new ItemLabelPosition(ItemLabelAnchor.CENTER, TextAnchor.CENTER));
    barrenderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator(
            "Series {0}, Value {1}", NumberFormat.getInstance()));
```

I am unable to see ToolTip for each bar

Am I missing something or maybe its not working via jsf ?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using JSF do you convert the chart into an image to show in the webpage?  If this is the case I don't think the tool tips can be preserved.

Comment: are there any other options ?

Comment: Are you able to use Java Server Faces?  [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/barChart.jsf) has charts with tooltips